# A 3-part combinatorics question with varying conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am not entirely sure about my approach to these questions (especially b) and I wanted to get some opinions:

**a)** There are $m$ identical-looking men (indistinguishable/ treated as not distinct elements, $m>=10$) in an elevator. At each of floors $2$ through $11$, at least one man leaves the elevator (not in an ordered line = the order in which they exit in each floor does not matter & We don't know whether all have left by the time the elevator reaches floor $11$). How many ways is it possible for these $m$ identical-looking men to exit the elevator according to these conditions?

**b)** What happens if this time men are distinguishable/distinct (it matters which men get off on which floor) and you notice that all men have emptied the elevator by floor $11$. How many ways is it possible for them to empty out of the elevator, again not in an ordered line (at least one man leaves the elevator on every floor, $m$ still $>=10$)?

**c)** Now, what happens if men are still distinct but $m>0$, you do not know whether at least one man exits the elevator or not (it is possible no one leaves on a given floor but all will have emptied the elevator by floor $11$) and it matters the exact order in which they leave the elevator on each floor?

Comment: I have corrected my mistake and I believe the answer is correct now. It passes the sanity check, at least. Please report if you find anything wrong or unusual.

Comment: **Please** do not ever destroy a question like that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question (a):

Let $m_i$ be the number of men that leave at the $i$-th floor. Then the number of ways is precisely the number of solutions to

$$\sum_{i=2}^{11}m_i \leq m \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(m_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \,\,m_i \geq 1)$$

Let $\widetilde{m_i}=m_i-1$, that is equivalent to the number of solution to

$$\sum_{i=2}^{11}\widetilde{m_i} \leq (m-10) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(\widetilde{m_i} \in \mathbb{Z}, \,\,\widetilde{m_i} \geq 0)$$

For each $0 \leq k \leq m-10$, the number of solutions to

$$\sum_{i=2}^{11}\widetilde{m_i} =k \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(\widetilde{m_i} \in \mathbb{Z}, \,\,\widetilde{m_i} \geq 0)$$

is a well known problem (see [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))), and the answer is $\binom{k+9}{9}$. So the final answer is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-10}\binom{k+9}{9}=\sum_{k=9}^{m-1}\binom{k}{9}=\binom{m}{10}$$

where we've used reindexation and the [hockey stick identity](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity).

### Question (b):

First, observe that, for each solution to

$$\sum_{i=2}^{11}m_i = m\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(m_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \,\,m_i \geq 1)$$

there are a number of possible configurations, because each man is now dinstinguishable from the others (which $m_2$ of the $m$ men leave on second floor? which $m_3$ of the $m$ men leave on the third floor? and so on).

For a solution $(m_2,m_3,\dots,m_{11})$, this is given by the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):

$$
\pmatrix{m\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11}}=\frac{m!}{m_2!\cdots m_{11}!}\,,
$$

Hence, the total number of configurations is:

$$T = \sum_{\substack{\displaystyle m_2+\,\dots\,+m_{11}=m\\\displaystyle m_2,\dots,m_{11}\geq 1}}\pmatrix{m!\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11}}$$

This look a bit troublesome to calculate. However, by the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):

$$S=\sum_{\substack{\displaystyle m_2+\,\dots\,+m_{11}=m\\\displaystyle m_2,\dots,m_{11}\geq 0}}\pmatrix{m!\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11}}={10}^{m}$$

Now, look into

$$N=\sum_{\substack{\displaystyle m_2+\,\dots\,+m_{11}=m\\\displaystyle m_2,\dots,m_{11}\geq 0}\\\displaystyle\text{At least one $m_j$ is $0$}}\pmatrix{m!\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11}}$$

and notice that $S=T+N$. Rewrite $N$ as:

$$N=\sum_{k=1}^9\left[\sum_{\substack{\displaystyle m_2+\,\dots\,+m_{11}=m\\\displaystyle m_2,\dots,m_{11}\geq 0}\\\displaystyle\text{Exactly $k$ of the $m_j$ are $0$}}\pmatrix{m!\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11}}\right]$$

For each $1 \leq k \leq 9$, there are $\binom{10}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ of the $10$ $m_j$'s to be $0$'s. Then, we may yet rewrite $N$ as:

\begin{align}
N&=\sum_{k=1}^9\binom{10}{k}\left[\sum_{\substack{\displaystyle m_2+\,\dots\,+m_{11-k}=m\\\displaystyle m_2,\dots,m_{11-k}\geq 1}}\pmatrix{m!\\m_2,\dotsc,m_{11-k}}\right]
\end{align}

Hummm, see the similarity of the term inside brackets to $T$? Indeed, define:

$$\mathcal{T}(n,m)=\sum_{\substack{\displaystyle a_1+\,\dots\,+a_{n}=m\\\displaystyle a_1,\dots,a_{n}\geq 1}}\pmatrix{m!\\a_1,\dotsc,a_{n}}$$

(so that $T=\mathcal{T}(10,m)$.) What we've shown is that $\mathcal{T}$ satisfies the following recursion for $n\geq 2$:

$$\mathcal{T}(n,m)=n^m-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\mathcal{T}(k,m)$$

where of course $\mathcal{T}(1,m)=1$.

---

> **Lemma:** For each $n \geq 1$, we have that:
>
> $$\mathcal{T}(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}{(-1)}^{n-k}k^m=n!\cdot S(m,n)$$
>
> where $S(\dot\ ,\dot\ )$ denotes a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

*Proof:* We use induction. Notice that $\mathcal{T}(1,m)=1$ according to the lemma's formula, so we need only check that the recursion is satisfied, that is, for $n\geq 2$ it holds that:

$$n!\cdot S(m,n)=n^m-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!\cdot S(m,k)$$

Rewrite it as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!\cdot S(m,k)=n^m$$

which is a well-known identity relating Stirling numbers of the second kind to [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). This completes the proof of the lemma.

---

Using the lemma, we find that the answer to question (b) is

$$\mathcal{T}(10,m)=10!\cdot S(m,10)$$

The answer shouldn't be too surprising if we interpret it combinatorially.

Indeed, $S(m,n)$ counts the number of ways to partition a set of $m$ labelled objects into $n$ non-empty and unlabelled sets. What happens here is as follows: first, we partition the $m$ men into $n=10$ non-empty floors (that is, at least one man will leave on each floor). The floors are as yet unlabelled: we don't know what number each floor is! For each such partition of men into 'not-yet-numbered' floors, there are $10!$ ways to choose a numbering of these floors (from the set $\{2,3,\dots,11\}$ of available floor numbers). Hence the result.

### Question (c):

The first thing we do is choose an order for the men to leave -- we do not yet know on which floor each man will leave, but we may choose the order. The number of possible orders is $m!$.

Next, we choose the number of men that will leave on each floor. This is equivalent to choosing a solution to

$$\sum_{i=2}^{11}m_i = m\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(m_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \,\,m_i \geq 0)$$

Like before, by 'stars and bars' there are $\binom{m+9}{9}$ solutions. Hence, the final answer is

$$\binom{m+9}{9}m!=\frac{{(m+9)}!}{9!}=\frac{{(m+9)}!}{362880}$$

FINAL EDIT: The answer should be correct now.